# How to bring previous and next button by default in fancybox 2 in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
My scenario is on clicking a button I trigger the "fancybox overlay" to show up few details.
How do i bring the previous and next buttons by default on this "fancybox overlay"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `visibility:` hidden; below style or comment in jquery.fancybox.css

```
.fancybox-nav span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the css

```
.fancybox-nav span {
      visibility: visible !important;
   }
```

`.fancybox-nav` may be your fancy box nav class